# Unable to fix Screen Resolution for different devices like projector,monitor of asp.net projet

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-ui

I am working on project in ASP.NET WEB APPLICATION in which I am having problem with screen Resolution. Whenever I connect my project execution to different devices like from laptop to monitor or to Projector, the fields, labels, drop down lists and other are randomly displaced on the screen. I want to have same display look irrespective of the device on which the out put is being seen. I have seen so many ways but I couldn't find the one which suits my scenario.I want to adjust the out put to be displayed in same way when the resolution is changed that is like from 1024*768 to 1280*1024, etc. I want the out put to be spread across the entire screen in same manner irrespective of the resolution.In the project the resolution for all the controls is declared in measure of pixels not on percentage based.I don't want to change pixels into percentage that makes me to change every where in the project but by keeping them as pixels I want to adjust the resolution whenever it is changed so that the controls will be evenly displaced. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a displacefactor, that displaces "objects" on x, and y axis by a value calculated from the resolution. I'd check if the "object" is on the left or the right side of the screen (by getting the width of the screen and if its bigger than the half then displacefactor is poisitive, if not then its negative, and you displace the object on the x axis), you can do that with the height so you can displace them on the y axis. I can't be more specific because i can't program C# nor javascript, but i hope you understand what i'm trying to explain.

Comment: will this displacefactor work even if the size is mentioned in pixels  rather than percentage. What I mean is by using this method can I be able to display my controls evenly irrespective of the resolution size that is selected?

Comment: You can calculate the displacefactor from the resolution, and if you want to "rescale" object you can set up a scalefactor that is also calculated from the resolution, you just have to set up the default values of the objects coords and the scale of the objects. Just experiment with it.